# Override an Include (Remove Path)

Tags: makefile, cmake, include

There is a library that I have downloaded that has the following include;

```
#include <http-parser/http_parser.h>
```

They provide their own library for it, which resides in the `http_parser` folder.

The ESP-IDF have `http_parser.h` included. If I change the `#include` to be `#include <http_parser.h>`, it compiles.

I'm curious - can this be done using the Make or CMake system without having to edit the .c source file?

Comment: It is **compiler** who parses `.c` source file and interprets `#include <http-parser/http_parser.h>` directive. I don't know a compiler option for modify paths in an include directive on the fly. So neither Make nor CMake can help you in that. You may, however, to automate fixing line `#include <http-parser/http_parser.h>` in the downloaded library. E.g., with a patch.

Comment: BTW, using `#include <http-parser/http_parser.h>` seems to be initially wrong: it has much less google hits than `#include <http_parser.h>`. E.g. project https://github.com/brimworks/lua-http-parser uses `http-parser/http_parser.h` path, but it refers to https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser project which definitely assumes inclusion via `http_parser.h`.

Comment: Same with the project I am looking at esp-homekit-demo. It includes a folder which ultimately includes nodejs/http-parser. I am using PlatformIO, so not sure how to fiddle with the library.json and folder structure to make this work. Also, as I said - it is included in ESP-IDF - so may as well use that (if it is functionally equivalent)

Comment: 1) Which compiler are you using? 2) How would you feel about a makefile creating a temporary copy of the source file, editing that, using and deleting it?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't/don't want to fix the source file, you can manipulate directory structure to match, e.g.:

```
$ cat Makefile
CPPFLAGS = -I.

test: test.o

test.o: http_parser/http_parser.h

http_parser/%.h : %.h
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        ln -sfr $< $(@D)
```

It will create a requested folder and make a symbolic link to an existing file, which will allow compilation to proceed:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <http_parser/http_parser.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  return 0;
}

$ make
mkdir -p http_parser
ln -sfr http_parser.h http_parser
cc  -I.  -c -o test.o test.c
cc   test.o   -o test

$ ls -l http_parser
lrwxrwxrwx 1 raspy raspy 16 Mar 11 22:29 http_parser.h -> ../http_parser.h
```